# Difference between django-openid and django-openid-auth?

Tags: django, openid

I found two python libs to perform openid authentication with django: [django-openid](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid/) and [django-openid-auth](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid-auth/). I don't get the difference between the two, mostly (I think) because I have no experience with the django authentication mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

openid-auth was last updated in [Oct 2007](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid-auth/source/list)

I guess, now the choice is simple. :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the django-openid-auth project has a recent release (version 0.2) on their [own project site](https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth) released one day after becomingGuru posted his answer!

I just tried both. For django-openid I had to change yadis imports to become:

```
from openid.yadis import xri
```

Which was done in some places and not others. I also had to change maxlength to max_length to work with newer django versions.

For django-openid-auth, it worked better right off the bat. One thing that I'll have to fine-tune is creating django users from the openid logins with:

*in settings.py:*

```
OPENID_CREATE_USERS = True
```

Right now, it's creating users in the django users table like *openiduser*, *openiduser2*, etc, which doesn't seem useful.